# Two session keys Flask application, weird

Tags: python, session, flask

SESSION_KEY="IDOGN2HHO43NjIVhrIe3i8mrrYtwQL3KsmBmt9En0N6G1n84b8Y1ddb+bGfcHqluL3gYwmkHxf/YiE8tQqTtXA=="; session=eyJfcGVybWFuZW50Ijp0cnVlfQ.CTXHug.DBJdQAKPKf2YiQGGTbiDW6DTEmI

As very obvious from my title my Flask application is setting two cookies. I couldn't understand such behaviour.
Please find snippet of my flask code below.

```
from flask import Flask, session, jsonify, request, make_response, Response
from base64 import b64encode
import os, dbConnect
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True
app.secret_key = 'A0Zr98j/3yX R~XHH!jmN]LWX/,?RT'

conn = dbConnect.connect()
curs=conn.cursor()

@app.route("/py/commandSend", methods=['POST'])
def reverse():
    data = {'a': 10, 'b': [{'c': False, 'd': False}, None]}
    return json.dumps(data)


@app.route("/py/session", methods=['POST'])
def application():
    now = datetime.now()
    token = b64encode(os.urandom(64)).decode('utf-8')
    expiryTime = now + timedelta(0, 450)
    curs.execute("""INSERT INTO sessions (session_id, session_expiry, ip_address) VALUES (%s, %s ,%s) """,(token, expiryTime, request.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]))
    conn.commit()
    response = make_response()
    response.set_cookie('SESSION_KEY',token)
    session.permanent = True
    return response

@app.route("/py/getClientIP", methods=['POST'])
def getClientIP():
    data = {}
    data['client_ip'] = request.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]
    js = json.dumps(data)
    resp = Response(js, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
    print(request.environ['HTTP_COOKIE'])

    return resp

@app.route("/py/sessionClose", methods=['POST'])
def sessionClose():
    curs.execute("DELETE FROM sessions")
    conn.commit()
    return 'Done'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Even chrome developer tools network tab shows two cookies generated, which is really weird and not able to find the solution. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your flask app setting two cookies is the expected behaviour given the code you have written here. I'll explain:

In flask you add something to the users session by using the session import:

```
import session
session['username'] = michael
```

Now in the users `session` cookie there will be the value `username=michael` (after decryption).

I think by calling `session.permanent = true` you are causing a relatively blank `session` cookie to be created.

The other way you can store content in cookies in flask is to use `response.set_cookie`:

```
response = make_response()
response.set_cookie('SESSION_KEY',token)
return response
```

This is creating a cookie called `SESSION_KEY` with the value of `token`. That's where the second cookie you see is coming from.

What this means is that the `SESSION_KEY` isn't encrypted, because it isn't a flask managed session. I assume you want to protect this `SESSION_KEY` so you should rewrite your code like so:

```
@app.route("/py/session", methods=['POST'])
def application():
    now = datetime.now()
    token = b64encode(os.urandom(64)).decode('utf-8')
    expiryTime = now + timedelta(0, 450)
    curs.execute("""INSERT INTO sessions (session_id, session_expiry, ip_address) VALUES (%s, %s ,%s) """,(token, expiryTime, request.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]))
    conn.commit()
    session['SESSION_KEY'] = token
    session.permanent = True
```

That will store your `SESSION_KEY` in the encrypted session cookie.

Comment: @Micahel  I did changes as you told but still multiple session cookies are getting generated.

Comment: Have you made sure you have deleted the cookie before testing again? If you use the same session to test and the cookies have a long life, then the cookie that was created last time will still exist. Easiest way to test is open a Private browsing tab and run your test. If the two cookies still exist then search your code for all `request.set_cookies` calls, perhaps you are creating it elsewhere.